# What happen to SketchFlow and what we should use instead?

Tags: visual-studio, sketchflow

What is the new **Microsoft way** of UI prototyping since VS2015 doesn't support SketchFlow projects.  *(I'm having hard time to accept that they removed such a useful tool without providing alternative)*

> I know we still have *PowerPoint StoryBoards* for basic UI mock-ups but I would like to use interactive prototypes through Visual Studio.  ***Therefore please do not suggest alternative products***

Comment: "SketchFlow. Blend for Visual Studio 2015 will not support SketchFlow projects. We encourage you to continue using Blend for Visual Studio 2013 if you require SketchFlow for your prototyping needs." => http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/11/13/blend-for-visual-studio-2015-preview.aspx

Comment: Thx but I posted here after I read that one and search on Internet.  I would like to know what is the roadmap etc.

Comment: I don't think there is one at the moment.

Comment: me neither thus [tweeted](https://twitter.com/cilerler/status/689527284269748225) to people who may have idea. Plus posted here.  I hope Microsoft folks may reply this question in the future...  

Comment: Does not look like SketchFlow will be making a comeback any time soon.  Did you find an acceptable replacement?  Or are you using VS2013?